# Word AddIn inactive state

Tags: c#, ms-word, registry, vsto, word-addins

I've a problem with my Word-AddIn.
When I start Word out of my application, it seems to crash with a document preview, which is also part of the application. The Word-AddIn is inactive.

I've checked the loadbeahavior in the registry...value is still 3. But when I look up the AddIn-State in Word (FILE -> OPTION -> Add-Ins), my AddIn is listed as inactive.

There is also no "DisabledItem" nor "StartUpItems" in the resiliency registry-element. Just one element in "DocumentRecovery"

How can I programly (C#) check the AddIn state?
Anyone familiar with this problem?

Comment: Do you get any specific errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [COMAddIns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192831(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Word Application class which returns a reference to the COMAddIns collection that represents all the add-ins currently loaded in Microsoft Word.

The [Connect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863828(v=office.15).aspx) property of the COMAddin class returns the state of the connection for the specified COMAddIn object. The Connect property returns True if the add-in is active; it returns False if the add-in is inactive. An active add-in is registered and connected; an inactive add-in is registered but not currently connected.

Be aware, Microsoft Office applications can disable add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when an add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the Startup event handler in your add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when an add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable an add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the add-in again.

See [How to: Re-enable an Add-in That Has Been Disabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268871.aspx) for more information.